# sending data to log file - shell script

Tags: file, shell, logging

Can you please explain these expressions to me:

```
cd - 1>> $LOG   // Q -  what 1 represent ?

./build_we2s all 1>> $LOG 2>> $LOG // Q -  what 2 represent ?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
1    stdout  Standard output
2    stderr  Standard error

cmd 1>> $LOG append stdout (only) to $LOG
cmd 1>> $LOG 2>>$LOG append stdout and stderr to $LOG
```

you could do

```
cmd >> $LOG 2>&1
```

or

```
cmd &>>$LOG
```

too

Answer (score 0):

1 => stdout.
2 => stderr.

They are the default file descriptors (fd) for stdin & stdout.